# User input scheme of 2d vector field on a 2d plane for navigation

Tags: movement, vector, input, control, strategy

I want to create a strategy game based on distributions of "units" which can be moved around and attack each other.
By distribution of units i mean that i don't have any discrete units instead is have a heat map which shows the concentration of units. If a group of units in attack range of enemy units the concentration in the area under attack will slowly dwindle.

Movement of a distribution of units thus follows a vector fields, allowing groups of units to be merged or split.
[image: Groups of units being merged, split and in general moving along vectors]
I have not decided whether i will only use the direction information or also the intensity/length (different parts are allowed to move at different speeds), this will depend on the input scheme.

### How can i make user efficiently input and update such vector fields while still being able to move and zoom around?

One idea i had is to use a "potential" field and use the partial derivative to generate the vector field which might look like this:

[image]

However i am not sure that is the best idea. The input device i am targeting would be a mouse with scroll wheel. If you can come up with elegant input scheme for another input device ((pressure sensitive?) touch, controller, joystick, motion capture ...) i would also welcome the contribution.

### How the input vector field will be used:

Bonus points, if you actually test your proposal.
In this case the update rule on a grid would be a discretization of this PDE (which is derived from the Fokker–Planck equation with no Diffusion):
$$\dfrac{\partial \text{Units}(x,y,t)}{\partial t} = -\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(\text{Units}(x,y,t)[\text{Input}_\vec{x}(x,y,t)+\text{Input}_\vec{y}(x,y,t)])  -\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(\text{Units}(x,y,t)[\text{Input}_\vec{x}(x,y,t)+\text{Input}_\vec{y}(x,y,t)]))$$

where $$ \text{Units}(x,y,t)$$ is the 2-d array containing the discretization of the distribution of units at time t and $$\text{Input}_\vec{y}(x,y,t)$$ is the y component of the vector field of the input vector field at coordinates x,y at time t.

Comment: [Check out this video about tech art in Obduction](https://gdcvault.com/play/1023211/Building-Obduction-Cyan-s-Custom) - around 25 minutes in, they show how they paint flow maps by converting click+drag swipes of the mouse into a vector field, like a paint stroke that flows in the direction and speed of movement. That might be applicable to your case, probably together with a decay over time so old orders eventually fade away.

Comment: @DMGregory This looks promising. Brush size could vary with zoom level and an onscreen slider. I will need to check whether arbitrary tangent spaces as you can construct with that tool don't create troops out of nothing.
If you feel like it please submit this proposal as answer, so i can accept it if turns out to be the best one.

Comment: I likely won't have time to write that up in detail this week, but you're welcome to share your own answer with your implementation if you find it works.